# Cast a stage child movieclip into a custom class extends movieclip AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, casting, movieclip

I'm creating a program where I add multiple Movieclips to the stage in Flash, instance name them 'item_#' per frame, and at runtime I pull these children into an array and dynamically cast them to a custom class called 'Item' which extends MovieClip.

```
function loadUpItems(): Array //loads items into ItemArray{
var ItemArray:Array = new Array(); //Dynamically holds the items_# for each scene

for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++) //loop number of children on stage
{

    if(getChildAt(i).name.substr(0,4) == "item") //if child is an item
    {
        trace("Item Child is: " + getChildAt(i));
        var mc:Item = new Item();       
        mc = getChildAt(i) as Item;
        mc.setItemX(getChildAt(i).x);
        mc.setItemY(getChildAt(i).y);
        mc.setItemNumber(Number(getChildAt(i).name.substr(5)));
        ItemArray[getChildAt(i).name.substr(5)] = mc; //Add to Items:array as instance numbered
        ItemArray[getChildAt(i).name.substr(5)].stop();
        trace("Loaded Item : " + ItemArray[getChildAt(i).name.substr(5)].itemName() + " : Frame : " + CurrentFrame);
    }
}
trace("ItemArray : " + ItemArray);
return ItemArray;}
```

The problem being I can't seem to cast them properly as I get a null at the point:

```
mc = getChildAt(i) as Item;
```

It worked when I was just pulling the items as MoviClips and didn't need to cast them:

```
mc = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
```

Help welcome,

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: sounds like you are adding them to the stage as MovieClip instances then trying to runtime upcast them to Item instances. If you do that then you line getChildAt(i) as Item will return null since it may look like an Item, but it isn't... it's a MovieClip.  Instead add them originally as Item instances and not MovieClip instances and you should be fine.

Comment: Have you applied library linkage? It won't work otherwise, and it must if you did :)

Comment: You can't cast if those items are not instances of that class in the fist place.

Comment: I see, I didn't have any library linkage, got it working now, thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: You might post your discovers as an answer to this question and potentially get reputation for providing valuable research to anyone who would stumble upon the same problem as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

I didn't apply library linkage. The base class of all the items was still set to MovieClip.

So I went to the items Properties...>Export for ActionScript.

And just changed the base class to my 'Item' class.

To easy.